# Well pump will not shut off

Tags: plumbing, water, well

Recently replaced an inline ball valve and now the well pump will not shut off when up to pressure. Since the valve wad the first from the holding tank i had to drain it. What's the solution to this issue. Any and all help is deeply appreciated

Comment: Is there a pump switch & is the new valve allowing water to the original height?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have blocked the pressure going to the pressure switch, if the valve is opened and your pump shuts off you will need to relocate the valve or pressure switch so the pump will shut off.

Comment: I am curious is the pressure gauge you are reading connected to the pressure switch? Is it correct? If you answer yes to both you may have to either adjust the switch or replace it.  I think it is coincidental, the valve should not have changed anything.